# Open a socket in Visual Studio C++ 2015 to a ethernet LMD Motor

Tags: visual-studio, sockets, visual-c++

I read and copy different code to connect an ethernet LMD motor but unsuccessfully unfortunately. I have any compilation or socket error.

I hope you could find what i do wrong.

This is my code

```
WSADATA WSAData;
SOCKET sock;

WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock < 0 ) { testcontrol.SetWindowTextW(L"socket error"); }

SOCKADDR_IN sin;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.155", &(sin.sin_addr));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(503);

if ( connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) ) {
    testcontrol.SetWindowTextW(L"connect error");
}

char *sendbuf = "MR 10000";
send(sock, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem is when i send command to the motor, the motor does nothing. I do it properly with the manufacturer software or with the socket test software here : [link](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/). When i use this softwares, it seems to have a connexion delay probably due to java code but i dont have it with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working corrected code :

```
WSADATA WSAData;
SOCKET sock;

// the dll is 2.2 version 
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WSAData);
// protocole is TCP
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sock < 0 ) { testcontrol.SetWindowTextW(L"socket error"); }

SOCKADDR_IN sin;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.155", &(sin.sin_addr));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(503);

if ( connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) ) {
    testcontrol.SetWindowTextW(L"connect error");
}
// You need a return carrier at the end of your cmd
char *sendbuf = "MR 10000\r";
send(sock, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);
```

Comment: How can i close this post ?

Comment: It is OK to accept your own answer (click the gray check mark at the top left). That is as "closed" as you want to make it. That way people can see the correct code in your answer if they have a similar question.